# Pure Julia implementation of BLAS-like Library

Tags: julia, d, blas

As far as I understand, Julia is linked against a Fortran BLAS library.

Given the interesting results obtained in D with [Mir GLAS](https://github.com/libmir/mir-glas), could a BLAS-like library be implemented in pure Julia?

If so, could one expect a similar performance boost as observed with Mir GLAS?

Comment: I doubt you can achieve near mir-glass performance with pure Julia BLAS implementation...

Comment: @DejanLekic There is no reason a Julia BLAS implementation could not be competitive. See e.g. here (https://discourse.julialang.org/t/we-can-write-an-optimized-blas-library-in-pure-julia-please-skip-op-and-jump-to-post-4/11634) for some initial experiments and discussion.

Comment: @DNF - I will believe it only when I see it! (2+ decades of "dealing" with dynamically typed languages make me sceptical)

Comment: @DejanLekic I thought it was based on something more specific, but ok.

Comment: @DejanLekic Julia isn't your traditional dynamic language.  It's a very good front-end for generating and managing (static) LLVM code... which is precisely what Mir GLAS uses.

Comment: @DejanLekic well there you go, there you see it. The packages are mentioned in the discourse. It already exists and benchmarks well, but only one function is implemented and optimized to Yingbo's laptop. It needs to add the other parts of BLAS and architecture-specific block sizes, which takes awhile. But the optimizing is pretty straightforward: optimize it like a static code and compile any dynamicness away. Julia allows you to do that.